# ReactJS: useEffect does not set correct length of Redux store array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a situation where I am populating several material-ui card components with counts of how many bills are associated with a logged-in user, the total hours spent on a job, etc. I have a Summary component with SummaryCard children, which take a value as a prop and then display it:

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { SectionTitle, SummaryCard } from '../../atoms'
import { css } from '@emotion/react'

const styles = makeStyles({
    summaryRow: {
        borderBottom: '3px solid #2c3e50',
        margin: '0 auto',
        padding: '0 2rem 1rem',
        width: '84vw'
    }
})

const Summary = () => {
    const classes = styles()
    let billsData = useSelector(state => state.dashboardData.billsData)
    let [billsCount, setBillsCount] = useState(3)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(billsData)
        console.log(billsData.data)
        console.log(billsData.data.length)
        setBillsCount(billsData.data.length)
    },[billsData])
  
    return (
        <Fragment> 
            <section css={summaryCSS} >
                <SectionTitle title='SUMMARY' />
                    <Grid classes={{ root: classes.summaryRow }} container spacing={4} >
                        <Grid item xs={3} >
                            <SummaryCard color='#4E73DF' title='NUMBER OF BILLS' type='Receipt' value={billsCount} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={3} >
                            <SummaryCard color='#f6c23e' title='HOURS BILLED' type='Hours' value={0} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={3} >
                            <SummaryCard color='#1CC88A' title='TOTAL EXPENSES' type='Dollar' value={0} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={3} >
                            <SummaryCard color='#E74A3B' title='CUSTOMERS SERVED' type='Customers' value={0} />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
            </section>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Summary
```

I've set the Redux store data equal to billsData (via useSelector), and the idea is to leverage the useEffect hook to set the state of billsCount whenever billsData updates. However, the line `setBillsCount(billsData.data.length)` sets the count to 0, even though I have logged proof to the console that this array is not empty:
[image: Console.log of billsData object, showing filled array]

Worse, setBillsCount is overwriting my initial billsCount value, which I have set to 3 to prove that useEffect is actually firing as expected, but not setting the correct value. The SummaryCard component then re-renders with the new 0 value, as shown:
[image: Screenshot of rendered Summary component]

Finally, here are screenshots of the React component, showing that the selector is filled but that the state is still 0, and also that the Redux store is filled, as expected:
[image: Screenshot of Summary React component state]
[image: Screenshot of Redux store]

So why is setBillsCount overwriting my billsCount to 0? And furthermore, if I make a change in my editor and re-save so that my localhost instance is updated, the correct value (18) will load in, as shown:
[image: Screenshot of updated Summary component]

I have tried several things, including: 1) adding an initialRender state and dependency, such that useEffect increments initalRender if it equals 0 to trigger a re-render, 2) creating a new array, pushing the billsData.data array into it, and trying to set billsCount with newArray.length, 3) implementing a temporary count variable and running a .forEach loop on the array to increment the count before setting the state with it, and 4) passing the billsData into the Summary component as {props} from the parent component.

UPDATE: after checking my Redux actions/reducers, I feel as though I am following the recommended structure, but I'm not certain:

```
export const addUser = user => ({
    type: 'ADD_USER',
    payload: user
})

export const addActivityData = data => ({
    type: 'ADD_ACTIVITY_DATA',
    payload: data
})

export const addBillsData = data => ({
    type: 'ADD_BILLS_DATA',
    payload: data
})

export const addCustomerData = data => ({
    type: 'ADD_CUSTOMER_DATA',
    payload: data
})

export const addJobsData = data => ({
    type: 'ADD_JOBS_DATA',
    payload: data
})

export const addWorkerData = data => ({
    type: 'ADD_WORKER_DATA',
    payload: data
})
```

```
dataReducer.js

const initialState = {}

export default function dataReducer (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_ACTIVITY_DATA': {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                activityData: action.payload
            })
        }
        case 'ADD_BILLS_DATA': {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                billsData: action.payload
            })
        }
        case 'ADD_CUSTOMER_DATA': {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                customerData: action.payload
            })
        }
        case 'ADD_JOBS_DATA': {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                jobsData: action.payload
            })
        }
        case 'ADD_WORKER_DATA': {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                workerData: action.payload
            })
        }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are mutating `state.dashboardData.billsData` in the reducer? I don't see how you have 2 logs showing an array of 18 and then log the length as 0. Maybe try to log this: `console.log('data at this moment:',JSON.stringify(billsData.data,undefined,2))`

Comment: I don't know why this is happening but I also don't see why you are saving the count to state rather than just using the count directly? `<SummaryCard color='#4E73DF' title='NUMBER OF BILLS' type='Receipt' value={billsData.data.length} />`

Comment: @LindaPaiste my fault, I forgot to mention that I had tried this already too, with the same result. The reason that I went down this path of setting state with useState/useEffect is because, when this approach failed, I figured that I would have to invoke useEffect to alter the child props and re-render the component.

Comment: @HMR This is a good idea, thanks, I'll look into whether I'm mutating the data. As for your second suggestion, I tried it with the same result: `data at this moment: []`.

Comment: @ChardBrez That is not the same result, in your posted images it says `Array(18)` however; when you try to log it as string you get the empty array that when logging the length gets you 0. This means that at some point you are mutating it after that log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think that I tracked the problem to my Firebase call implementation. Rather than storing all of my Firebase/Firestore 'get' functions in a separate Firebase class and accessing them by wrapping my components with this HOC, I simplified the process and just get the Firebase data and dispatch it directly to the Redux store on sign-in with the useEffect hook:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        
        const addUserToStore = async () => {
            dispatch(allActions.userActions.addUser(userState))
        }

        const getBills = async (id) => {
            firestore.collection('Bill Fanout').where('Client', '==', `${id}`).onSnapshot( function (querySnapshot) {
                let billsArr : any[] = []
        
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    billsArr.push(doc.data())
                })
                
                dispatch(allActions.dataActions.addBillsCount(billsArr.length))
                dispatch(allActions.dataActions.addBillsData(billsArr))
            })
        }

        const getCustomers = async (id) => {
            db.child('Customer Fanout').child(id).on('value', snapshot => {
                const custArr : any[] = []
                const obj = snapshot.val()

                for (let prop in obj) {
                    let innerObj = {}
                    innerObj[prop] = obj[prop]
                    custArr.push(innerObj)
                }

                dispatch(allActions.dataActions.addCustomerCount(custArr.length))
                dispatch(allActions.dataActions.addCustomerData(custArr))
            })
        }

        const getJobs = async (id) => {
            db.child('Jobs Board Fanout').child(id).on('value', snapshot => {
                const jobArr : any[] = []

                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    jobArr.push(doc.val())
                })

                dispatch(allActions.dataActions.addJobsCount(jobArr.length))
                dispatch(allActions.dataActions.addJobsData(jobArr))
            })
        }

        if (userState.isLoggedIn) {
            addUserToStore()
            // Gets the bills data
            getBills(userState.uid)
            getCustomers(userState.uid)
            getJobs(userState.uid)
                .then(() => setDataAddedToStore(true))       
        }


    }, [userState.isLoggedIn])
```

And now the useEffect hooks in my child components properly update the component state, which get passed into the final components directly as props.